# scrapy startprojectでアクセス拒否の時の対処法

Tags: python, web-scraping

`scrapy startproject [プロジェクト名]`
を実行した際に
`PermissionError: [WinError 5] アクセスが拒否されました。`
と表示されます。
対処法を教えてください。

実行環境はwindows11 anacondaです。

Comment: こんな解説記事があるようですので、いったん最初からこれに従って一通りの作業を試してみてはどうでしょう？ [図解！Python Scrapyの使い方を徹底解説！(サンプルコード付きチュートリアル)](https://ai-inter1.com/python-scrapy-for-begginer/)

Comment: エラーはTraceBackを省略せずに書いたほうがよさそうです